# How do the doping and temeprature change the electric field in pn junction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

How do the doping and temeprature change the electric field in pn junction?

Professor asked me that and I didn't know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Junction potential is :

The zero external bias, built-in, junction potential or scl potential is given by:

φ = kT/q = 0.0259eV
 at room temperature, 300 K.

where
q is the electron charge, 1.6 x  10^-19C

k is Boltzmann’s constant, 1.38 x 10^-23J/K

T is the junction temperature, K.

So to your question, higher the temperature, higher the potential.